# Unity OverlapCollider ArgumentNullException error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

for testing I have next code:

```
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T) && enemyType == 1)
        {
            Physics2D.OverlapCollider(healCollider, filter, enemyColliders);
            foreach (Collider2D collider in enemyColliders)
            {
                Debug.Log(collider);
                if (collider.CompareTag("enemy"))
                {
                    Debug.Log("works");
                }
            }
        }
```

(It is in the update), also I have   `private Collider2D[] enemyColliders;`, but when I click T it gives me next error:[image]

Also here is the my filters [image]
I tried to change filters but nothing happened, also my filter might be wrong but I dont know that should I check here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you the issue is with the `results` parameter.

You are passing `enemyColliders` but it seems to be `null`!

[`Physics2D.OverlapCollider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCollider.html) requires either an initialized array like

```
private Collider2D[] enemyColliders = new Collider2D[5];
```

where the `5` means you are only interested in the first `5` hits.

Or if you need a dynamic amount of hits you should rather use a list like

```
private List<Collider2D> enemyColldiers = new List<Collider2D>();
```

---

Also note that [`Physics2D.OverlapCollider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCollider.html) returns

> **int** Returns the number of results placed in the results array.

If your array is longer than the amount of hits it will only fill the hits in the `x` first items of the array and the rest of the elements in the given array will also be invalid (`null`)!

You should either take this returned amount into account and rather iterate like

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T) && enemyType == 1)
{
    var count = Physics2D.OverlapCollider(healCollider, filter, enemyColliders);
    // ONLY ITERATE OVER VALID ENTRIES
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var collider = enemyColliders[i];
        Debug.Log(collider);
        if (collider.CompareTag("enemy"))
        {
            Debug.Log("works");
        }
    }
}
```

or alternatively at least check if the collider "exists" like

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T) && enemyType == 1)
{
    Physics2D.OverlapCollider(healCollider, filter, enemyColliders);
    foreach (Collider2D collider in enemyColliders)
    {
        // SKIP IF NULL ITEM
        if(!collider) continue;

        Debug.Log(collider);
        if (collider.CompareTag("enemy"))
        {
            Debug.Log("works");
        }
    }
}
```